# t sql delete duplicates rows from 2 tables

Tags: sql-server

I have 2 tables:

- FirstTable
- SecondTable

`FirstTable` has these columns

```
sales_ID varchar(250)
product_ID int
```

`SecondTable` has these columns

```
sales_ID varchar(250)
product_ID int
CreateDate datetime
```

If `FirstTable`'s `sales_ID` and `product_ID` match to `SecondTable`'s `sales_Id` and `product_ID`, and also if `SecondTable`'s `CreatedDate` is 07.04.2015, I need to delete the row from `SecondTable`

I tried like this:

```
delete from SecondTable
WHERE sales_Id IN (SELECT sales_Id FROM FirstTable) 
  and product_ID IN (SELECT product_ID FROM FirstTable) 
  and CreatedDate = '07-04-2015'
```

However it deletes all rows and also it is not correct (not working) query according to what I want.

How can I delete duplicate rows if product_ID equals product_ID and  sales_ID equal sales_ID and CreatedDate equals 07.04.2015 from `SecondTable`?

Hope you understand my bad english

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
delete from secondtable
from secondTable st
inner join firstTable ft on st.sales_id = ft.sales_id
    and st.product_id = ft.product_id
    and st.CreatedDate = '2015-07-04'
```

note you'll probably want to wrap the above in a transaction to make sure you're not deleting unwanted records - or turn the statement into a select:

```
select st.*
from secondTable st
inner join firstTable ft on st.sales_id = ft.sales_id
    and st.product_id = ft.product_id
    and st.CreatedDate = '2015-07-04'
```

Answer (score 3):

That's because it's purely checking for the presence of the sales id in the second table and the product id, seperately, not on the same record.

Try for example

```
Delete T2
FROM firsttable AS T1
INNER JOIN secondtable T2
on T1.sales_id = T2.sales_id
AND T1.product_id = T2.product_id
WHERE T1.CreatedDate = '20150407'  -- assuming you mean 7th April?
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DELETE 
  FROM SecondTable t2
  JOIN FirstTable t1
    ON t1.sales_ID = t2.sales_ID
   AND t1.product_ID = t2.product_ID
   AND t1.CreatedDate = '2015-07-04'
```